# Matching a String having '%' as a character

Tags: sql

I want to match a String using Like operator. The challenge is having '%' as a character in my string.

```
i.e. Row1 : Column = CT%CNV!XYZABCD...
     Row2 : Column = CTXXXCNV!XYZABCDE...
```

If I use "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column like 'CT%CNV!%'. It doesn't consider '%' as a character and the statement returns both rows.

I need to return the first row only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shoud use ***escape*** keyword:

```
select *
  from MyTable
 where Column like 'CT\%CNV!XYZABCD%' escape '\'
```

here `'\%'` is treated as a *plain symbol*, while `'%'` is *wild card* one

Answer (score 5):

You can use brackets to escape the percent sign :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column like 'CT[%]CNV!%'
```

Comment: aleroot, I believe this statement has a lot of potential to help me but it is not working on mine (plsql). Am I missing something. Do they have different escape style?